# Calling Resource files in Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have resource files for multilingual support
In cshtml files i can directly access the resource files
but in when i try the following line in my jscript, its printing the line as it is

```
$('#message').html('@Resources.Login').delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

and i tried some  other way also

```
var login = "@Resources.Login";
                $('#message').html(login).delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

but stil its showing the line as "Resources.login"

Comment: you can't do it this way... there are 2 ways to do it: 1) register a hidden field in page with your resource value and call that hidden field id value; 2) use a webservice that will call your resource via ajax

Comment: @HellBaby, no need to use hidden field or ajax. Because, he dont send any parameter to server, he want to show server side parameter in view.

Comment: Do you get any compilation error? May be you need to get it with its namespace like this: `@YourApplication.Resources.Login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rendered the resource file in cshtml as follows

```
<script>
var Login="@Resources.Login";
</Script>
```

and called the variable in my js file as follows

```
$('#message').html(Login).delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

thank you for your help all :)